# How does Twitter recognize the main photo in a webpage?

Tags: css, twitter

I have a problem making Twitter display the main image in the "Media" sidebar, when I share a page from my photo sharing service. Is there a specific CSS naming convention which I have to stick to? For example, I know that Facebook does look for some specific class names and tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not work quite the same unless you are a content partner for Twitter. However since October 2011 you can use the statuses/update_with_media POST request on upload.twitter.com to achieve more or less the same effect.

In short you can use these Parameters in the `media[]` array.

```
"sizes": {
  "large": {
    "w":...
    "resize":...
    "h":...
  },
  "medium": {...},
  "small": {...},
  "thumb": {...}
},
"media_url_https": "...",
"expanded_url": "...",
"id_str": "...",
"url": "...",
"id": ...,
"type": "...",
"indices": [],
"display_url": "...",
"media_url": "..."
}
```

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/statuses/update_with_media contains full details and an example request

Remember **you** will have to share the image and post the tweet via the API as otherwise twitter does not get the media[] parameter.